# How to make font size independent of screen resolution and monitor size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on one application in which I want to make font size which is independent of screen resolution and screen size. The font size should be same in all resolutions and all screen sizes. How to do it with javascript and css?

I think Pixel per point is hardware related thing so i am not sure javascript and css have access of it.

I tried many alternatives but couldn't find exact solution.

Comment: What should happen if the user connect their computer to a projector?

Comment: I can appreciate the nature of your question, but for accessibility and usability for sight impaired people, this could be a dangerous wire to walk.

Comment: @rimunro , I don't have that requirement , In my application I need to maintain font size for only computer monitor .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good, universal solution. In my opinion, you should just consider that it's not possible. [This article](http://alistapart.com/column/responsive-typography-is-a-physical-discipline) was recently published, and suggests a (long-term) solution to that problem. It's long-term because it depends on multiple players (hardware and software manufacturers) to work out.

To quote the author:

> It’s ridiculous that we can send robots to Mars yet it’s still virtually impossible to render a glyph on a web page and say with confidence: “If you measure this glyph on your screen with a ruler, it will be exactly 10 millimeters wide.”

Comment: hehe, yes, because on a screen with 50x50px a fontsize of 16px makes no sence, so the relative ppi or dpi is set so, that you can read the information instead of styling correct.

Answer (score 5):

You can use points (`pt`), which are based on 1/72 of an inch.  This is a unit that traditionally comes from printing.  Now, it depends on whether or not the device is configured properly, whether or not this size will be the same from monitor to monitor.  It often isn't, but some devices are aware of their physical screen sizes.  You can also use inches `in`, centimeters `cm`, and millimeters `mm`.

Use this size, in conjunction with `ems`, which are relative sizes.  That way, the whole site can scale up and down as needed.

```
body {
    font-size: 12pt;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
p {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Old fashioned [points](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) should work.

Example:

```
<style>
p
{
    font:15pt;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The `pt` unit, like any CSS unit, may depend on screen resolution, see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths

Comment: It's worth commenting that the reason this works is because points correlate to inches instead of pixels. Using `.2in` would also work. All of that being said, in CSS points and inches depend on resolution, so they will never be independent.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this because you can't be sure what the true size of the users monitor is, unless you have control of the computers being used.

It's possible for a user to have 2 monitors connected at once in and be set so the same elements of the screen appear at different sizes on each one.

Comment: It doesn't work universally, but some devices are configured in such a way where it does often work.  This is particularly true with mobile devices.

Comment: With media queries you can know the client display size.

Comment: @Nelson, Media queries have nothing to do with it.  If the client knows its dimensions, then physical units will work in all of your CSS, media queries or not.  Many clients to not know their physical display dimensions, but many do.

Comment: @rimunro , then I can make application in which user can select their screen size . for example if user have screen 24-inch widescreen LCD then how to do it resolution independent ?

Answer (score 0):

```
html {font-size: 14px /* in example */}
```

this does every sibling element of html give an relative size, which means

```
body { font-size: 100% } /* is 14px now */
```

as well

```
div { font-size: 1em } /* should be 14px also */
```

its also possible to change html font-size with javscript, and all relative sizes should work as expected. with jQuery you could access the body's font-size and set it to some size calculated from screensize. even working would be `@media () { your css here }` rules for any kind of application in different devices.

```
var fontsize=14+'px';
jQuery('body').css('font-size',fontsize);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use cm and mm:

```
<span style="font-size: 2cm;">i am big</span>
<span style="font-size: 2mm;">i am tiny</span>
```

Comment: I wish that actually worked... Try it on some monitors, then measure the results.

Comment: @bfavaretto, But it does!  Try it on some mobile devices, then measure the results.  It does not work universally... not even close... but it does work in many cases.

Comment: @Brad I just tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LnYHB/) on my iMac and iPhone, and the result was off in both cases (off by ~25%). Maybe it does work for fonts only, not general sizing?

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you can't make font size completely independent of screen resolution. What you can do is use media queries to target different screen sizes and resize your font accordingly.

```
body { font-size: 16px; }
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    body { font-size: 112.5%; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    body { font-size: 125%; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    body { font-size: 137.5%; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    body { font-size: 150%; }
}
```

Those are just example values – you'll have to experiment with your app at various sizes and see what looks best. [Trent Walton's](http://trentwalton.com/) site is a good example of this – resize your browser window and see what happens to the text size.

If you size all your fonts using em or rem units, you only need to adjust the body font size and the rest of the values will scale proportionately.